# Quartz scheduler deadlocking with itself after using a serializable transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, quartz-scheduler, guice, mybatis

I've got a system with MySQL InnoDB tables, a clustered Quartz scheduler and MyBatis for the db layer.

Quartz runs a job every 30 seconds checking some stuff in the db. Everything has worked fine until recently, when I had to add an org.mybatis.guice.transactional.Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, executorType=ExecutorType.BATCH) annotation for a service method that actually does not even touch the data that the apparently failing trigger's job would touch.

So, now what happens is that after using that transactionalized service method for a while, after which it probably has failed against a concurrent call of itself (there is nothing in the logs about this though), every 30 seconds I get an exception in the logs for a deadlock in the Quartz jobs, and MySQL tells me the deadlock was the following:

> LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
>
> 160226 12:20:00
>   *** (1) TRANSACTION: TRANSACTION 28465C8, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap
>   size 376, 2 row lock(s) MySQL thread id 229934, OS thread handle
>   0x7efcefcf7700, query id 76969784 server-node2 192.168.0.8
>   system-username Sorting result SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP,
>   NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME =
>   'CloudScheduler' AND TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING' AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <=
>   1456482030017 AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR != -1 AND
>   NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= 1456481940018)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC,
>   PRIORITY DESC
>   *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 737 n bits 128 index `PRIMARY` of table
>   `cloudsystem`.`QRTZ_TRIGGERS` trx id 28465C8 lock mode S locks rec but
>   not gap waiting Record lock, heap no 55 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18;
>   compact format; info bits 0  0: len 19; hex
>   5468657265436c6f75645363686564756c6572; asc CloudScheduler;;  1: len
>   29; hex 41646d696e5573657253657474696e7355706461746554726967676572;
>   asc UserSettingsUpdateTrigger;;  2: len 7; hex 44454641554c54; asc
>   DEFAULT;;  3: len 6; hex 0000028465c2; asc     e ;;  4: len 7; hex
>   20000004ca2763; asc      'c;;  5: len 23; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e6773557064617465; asc
>   UserSettingsUpdate;;  6: len 17; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e6773; asc UserSettings;;  7: SQL NULL; 
>   8: len 8; hex 800001531d1811b0; asc    S    ;;  9: len 8; hex
>   800001531d179c80; asc    S    ;;  10: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;; 
>   11: len 8; hex 4143515549524544; asc ACQUIRED;;  12: len 4; hex
>   43524f4e; asc CRON;;  13: len 8; hex 80000153195c6d28; asc    S \m(;; 
>   14: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;  15: SQL NULL;  16:
>   len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;;  17: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
>
> *** (2) TRANSACTION: TRANSACTION 28465C2, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 10 lock struct(s), heap size
>   1248, 15 row lock(s), undo log entries 1 MySQL thread id 230109, OS
>   thread handle 0x7efcef9e7700, query id 76969780 server-node1
>   192.168.0.7 system-username Updating UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET TRIGGER_STATE = 'ACQUIRED' WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'CloudScheduler' AND
>   TRIGGER_NAME = 'UserSettingsUpdateTrigger' AND TRIGGER_GROUP =
>   'DEFAULT' AND TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING'
>   *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 737 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `cloudsystem`.`QRTZ_TRIGGERS` trx id
>   28465C2 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap Record lock, heap no 55
>   PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0  0: len 19;
>   hex 5468657265436c6f75645363686564756c6572; asc CloudScheduler;;  1:
>   len 29; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e7355706461746554726967676572; asc
>   UserSettingsUpdateTrigger;;  2: len 7; hex 44454641554c54; asc
>   DEFAULT;;  3: len 6; hex 0000028465c2; asc     e ;;  4: len 7; hex
>   20000004ca2763; asc      'c;;  5: len 23; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e6773557064617465; asc
>   UserSettingsUpdate;;  6: len 17; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e6773; asc UserSettings;;  7: SQL NULL; 
>   8: len 8; hex 800001531d1811b0; asc    S    ;;  9: len 8; hex
>   800001531d179c80; asc    S    ;;  10: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;; 
>   11: len 8; hex 4143515549524544; asc ACQUIRED;;  12: len 4; hex
>   43524f4e; asc CRON;;  13: len 8; hex 80000153195c6d28; asc    S \m(;; 
>   14: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;  15: SQL NULL;  16:
>   len 2; hex 8000; asc   ;;  17: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
>
> *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 759 n bits 120 index `IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST` of table
>   `cloudsystem`.`QRTZ_TRIGGERS` trx id 28465C2 lock_mode X locks rec but
>   not gap waiting Record lock, heap no 51 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5;
>   compact format; info bits 0  0: len 19; hex
>   5468657265436c6f75645363686564756c6572; asc CloudScheduler;;  1: len
>   7; hex 57414954494e47; asc WAITING;;  2: len 8; hex 800001531d1811b0;
>   asc    S    ;;  3: len 29; hex
>   41646d696e5573657253657474696e7355706461746554726967676572; asc
>   UserSettingsUpdateTrigger;;  4: len 7; hex 44454641554c54; asc
>   DEFAULT;;
>
> *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

So this makes me wonder. It is possible that an instance of the serializable transaction "elsewhere" has failed, but that shouldn't cause this phenomenon, which occurs repeatedly and each and every time. There also should are no  multiple scheduler jobs running at the same time either.

Another issue is that the @Transactional annotation does not seem to roll back the transaction -- there is corrupted data in the database after these deadlocks start showing up. Interestingly, elsewhere in the application where transactions are not serializable, rollbacks on exceptions do work correctly.

The MyBatis documentation is not very verbose about these issues, but is there something else I need to be doing to make my transactions safely serializable than

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, executorType=ExecutorType.BATCH)
public void doCoolStuff(...) {

}
```

Comment: Reconsider your isolation level; serializable! You should also try to make sure that only one instance of this services exists i.e. service executions time should not overlap.

Comment: Neither is an option. The transactions need to be serializable because they must be performed as-if they occurred one after the other, and obviously, the transactionality is there exactly because the service calls can and will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer but at the same time is too much information to put in a comment.

I would like to share some of my thoughts.

1. Are you 100% sure about the affirmation below? As you may already know, I would expect this sort of problem if your service and your Quartz jobs use the same tables at any point.

> "annotation for a service method that actually does not even touch the
>   data that the apparently failing trigger's job would touch."

2. It sounds to me that your Quartz jobs and your Transactions are colliding. Therefore, you may need to implement some sort of synchronization strategy. For example, you could add a transaction manager or you could add some sort of synchronized blocks in your code to avoid this problem.

Cheers,

Comment: I subsequently went and solved this with locking, but I certainly am still interested in why this happened... yes, I am quite positive that the data is not being touched. However I guess serializable transactions may have a rather broad idea of what is being touched... and MySQL isn't too good at these kinds of things, or that at least is my impression.

I'm not really sure what kind of an additional transaction manager would be required in this Guice+Mybatis setup -- certainly it is the database and not some explicit synchronized blocks in the Java code that have to handle these things!